# Group dataframe by similar rows

Tags: python, excel, regex, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have an excel file, with expenses that I need to group by the same concept. For simplicity, the dataframe would be something like this:

| Date | Concept | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07-12-2021 | A 01 | -100 |
| 01-12-2021 | A 02 | -150 |
| 30-11-2021 | B 01 | -50 |
| 29-11-2021 | C 01 | -25 |
| 23-11-2021 | D 01 | -70 |
| 22-11-2021 | C 02 | -80 |
| 19-11-2021 | B 02 | -65 |
| 18-11-2021 | B 03 | -25 |
| 17-11-2021 | A 03 | -30 |
| 16-11-2021 | D 02 | -120 |

The concept 'A 0X', refer to the same general concept 'A' but it has different identifiers. **Bear in mind that concept 'A 0X' is for the sake of simplicity, but the concept will be a more complex expression**

I am trying using this code to group by the same concept:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Expenses.xlsx")
df.groupby('Concept')['Amount'].apply(list)
```

The problem is that with this code I can not group all concepts 'A0X', 'B0X', 'C0X' as the same general concept 'A', 'B' or 'C'.

The final result I need would be:

**Total expenses**

| Concept | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 280 |
| B | 140 |
| C | 105 |
| D | 190 |

What I need is to know how to implement the **groupby method with regex expressions**.

Comment: Provide the Data as actual text an not as images please.

Comment: Have you tried using regex (import re) - example of how to use regex with pandas <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495905/pandas-groupby-by-partial-string>

Comment: @sunnytown I already put the data as table

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group by the first letter of the Concept column, you can use the pandas string functions in a groupby.

```
df_total = df.groupby(df['Concept'].str.split(' ').str[0]).sum().reset_index()
```

This returns:

```
>>> df_total
    Concept Amount
0   A       -280
1   B       -140
2   C       -105
3   D       -190
```

If you want the absolute value of the Amount column:

```
df_total['Amount'] = df_total['Amount'].abs()
```

Comment: It definitely works as your solution. However, the concept 'A 0X' is for the sake of simplicity. In the real case, the concept is much more complex, and I think I should attempt that using regex